# Supplying invalid TFS credentials for test purposes

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm having a scenario where a test is supplying invalid TFS credentials in order to fail authentication. However, `TfsTeamProjectCollection` is picking up my own credentials and always succeeds the call to `Authenticate()`. Is there a way to force invalid credentials? Here's what I am doing:

```
var account = new NetworkCredential(user.UserName, user.Password, user.Domain);
var provider = new NetworkCredentialsProvider(account);
teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri(serverUri),
    provider);
teamProjectCollection.Authenticate(); // should throw with invalid credentials
```

The `NetworkCredentialsProvider`class simply returns the `NetworkCredential`supplied in its constructor.

Previously this was possible with the `TeamFoundationServer` class (which is now deprecated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer I was looking for:

```
var account = new NetworkCredential(user.UserName, user.Password, user.Domain);
teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverUri),account);
teamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
```

Sorry for the noise!